# Android Emulators not launching on Mac

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am trying to test my NativeScript Application on an Android emulator. So I followed the NativeScript instructions and installed the sdk and set up the emulator as instructed. But whenever I want to run an emulator (manually from Android Studio), nothing happens. I can see the "starting AVD" message on the bottom of Android Studio but there is no emulator popping out and no error displayed. Can someone tell me what might be wrong or where I can "debug" to see if he throws an error?

Comment: Have you installed HAXM?

Comment: Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer) version 6.2.0 is installed according to the android-sdk